# How to display Euro sign in pdf using jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I'm using XML to produce a jasper report with Java and Intellij IDE, jasper version is 5.0.4.

On the `xml` file there is Euro sign `€` but when the report is created on pdf, I see  `â‚¬` instead of `€`

On the top of `xml` file I have the following encoding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

And this is how I add Euro symble to the xml:

```
    <textFieldExpression>
      <![CDATA["Please send the amount of " + $V{total}.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP) + " € to the bankaccount ..."]]>
    </textFieldExpression>
```

**How does it come and what should I add to the `xml` file to resolve this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the jasperreports version from 5.0.4 to 6.17.0 and it solved the issue. In my opinion the reason why it doesn't display the symbol on correct why was that I changed java from 1.7 to 11 but I did not touche the jasperreports version.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.17.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
<dependency>
```

Comment: There is no reason do have this question open i guess. You can now mark the question as answered.